# Advice for MongoDB schema design for social media post

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have been using MongoDB for my application but would like to add a social media post feature into the system. However, given the requirements, I find that it is not easy to come up with a MongoDB schema that would be effective for my use case. Any expert here care to share their suggestions?

The requirements are:

1. User can post social media post (imagine instagram posts)
2. User will view social media posts by other users
3. When a post is on a user screen for 5 second, we will record that the user has seen the post
4. Post that are seen will be appears in the user's social media feed

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can refer below schema which we require to manage users and their post along with post history like ( who liked, who watched and who add comments)

```
// Users schema
const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }
});

// Post related media schema
const postMediaSchema = new Schema({
    url: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }
}, {
    _id: false
})

// Post schema
const postSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'users',
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    media: [postMediaSchema],
    tags: [String]
});

// Users and posts relation schema 
const postWatchHistory = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'users',
    },
    postId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'posts',
    },
});

// Post liked history schema
const postLikedHistory = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'users',
    },
    postId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'posts',
    },
});

// Post comment history schema
const postCommentHistory = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'users',
    },
    postId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'posts',
    },
    text:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    status:{
        type: String,
        enum:['Y', 'N'],
        default:'N',
        trim: true
    }
});
```

Comment: While fetching the posts how would you check if user liked, watched or commented on the post?